# Showing that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ using the squeeze theorem and a few inequalities

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to show that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ using the following inequalities:
$$ \frac{\pi^2}{(2n+1)^2} \frac{n(2n-1)}{3} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{\pi^2}{(2n+1)^2}\left(n+\frac{n(2n-1)}{3}\right) $$

$$ \zeta(2):=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

When I compute the limit of the left side I end up either finding $+\infty * 0$ or $\frac{+\infty}{+\infty}$. How can I proceed?

Comment: The limiy of both LHS and RHS is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$: Put the expresion in common denominator and then, divide both numerator and denominator by $n^2$.

Answer (score 2):

If you expand out the left-hand side, you get

$$\frac{2\pi^2 n^2 - \pi^2 n}{12n^2 + 12n + 3}$$

Since this is a ratio of polynomials of the same degree, the limit as $n \to \infty$ is given by the ratio of the leading coefficients. Thus,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2\pi^2 n^2 - \pi^2 n}{12n^2 + 12n + 3} = \frac{2 \pi^2}{12} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

---

If the fact that the ratio of polynomials induces this limit isn't obvious, consider the general case:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0}{b_n x^n + b_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + b_1 x + b_0}$$

Then multiply the top and bottom by $1/x^n$. You get

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a_n + a_{n-1}/x + a_{n-2}/x^2 + \cdots + a_1/x^{n-1} + a_0/x^n}{b_n + b_{n-1}/x + b_{n-2}/x^2 + \cdots + b_1/x^{n-1} + b_0/x^n}$$

Clearly this limit is given by $a_n/b_n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why I wasn't expanding the expression correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For $c\in\{-1,\,2\}$,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(2n+c)}{(2n+1)^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2(1+\tfrac{c}{2n})}{4n^2(1+\tfrac{1}{2n})^2}=\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\tfrac{c}{2n}}{(1+\tfrac{1}{2n})^2}.$$Now two [famous](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Combination_Theorem_for_Limits_of_Functions/Real/Quotient_Rule#Proof) [results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Proof) complete the proof.